# SwiftUI: Accessibility sound feedback for a draggable element

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, swiftui, uiaccessibility

I am making an application that works essentially like a simple Drag-and-Drop Playground with the command blocks on the left and a droppable area on the right. I want to make it fully compatible with VoiceOver and I'm running into trouble with some of the accessibility aspects since this is my first Swift application.

This is what the playground currently looks like: [(App Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5anO.png)

My goal is to provide the users with audio cues/feedback while they are dragging the elements to help them figure out what part of the screen they are currently at. The ideal functionality would be exactly like what one uses when editing an iOS device's Home screen (the arrangement layout of the apps).

When trying to rearrange apps on the home screen with VoiceOver enabled, you hear a row/column alert when you are dragging an app over an open area. I want a similar type of feedback that says "Droppable Area" when you are over the correct area (see [scenario 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJCAR.png)).

When trying to rearrange apps on the home screen with VoiceOver enabled, you hear a sound when you tap on an area that has no app icon. (This also happens when you are not editing the layout and simply tap on an open area with no app.) I want that noise to be what you hear when you drag a command over an area that is not droppable (see [scenario 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kJWw.png)).

Any ideas on how this might be possible or good references to look at?